# Identify the commits that were made in the last push

Tags: python, python-3.x, push, git-push, gitpython

Is there a way to determine which commits that were pushed during the last push event using the GitPython library?

The only thing I've found is the ability to search for a commits made during some time range, but it doesn't seem like a reliable way to solve this problem.

**UPD**
I've got variable from web hook `git_previous_commit` and tring to do it this way, but I don't get the results, namely the paths to the files that have been changed.

```py
repo = Repo(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
for commit in repo.iter_commits(rev=f'{git_previous_commit}..HEAD'):
    commit_object = repo.commit(commit)

    diffs = chain(
       commit_object.diff("HEAD").iter_change_type("M"),
       commit_object.diff("HEAD").iter_change_type("A"),
     )

     for diff in diffs:
        print(diff.b_path)
```

Comment: I tried your code with no modifications and it works. Maybe you do not see the console output?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way, unless you write a hook that stores the last commit on each push.

Comment: What if I can get the hash of the last commit? But there may be several in commits in one push and I don't know how to get others.

Comment: Yes, use the commit hash. ``git rev-list <since_hash>..HEAD``

Comment: Thank you. Updated my question since I'm still looking for a way to do this via GitPython.